# Oracle NOT pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to do a select AFTER I do a case statment

i.e.

```
 select x from dual  ( x is actually a variable in a report writer tool) 
 case when x = 'equipment' 
     select * from inside_sales
 else
     select * from outside_sales
 end
```

can't use PL/SQL

any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you could show some example data and your desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select * from inside_sales where x = 'equipment'
union all
select * from outside_sales where x <> 'equipment';
```

Note:  The second condition is slightly more complicated if `x` can be `NULL`.

Comment: `when` doesn't seem correct when there's no `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. But what to do with retrieved data?

```
create function sales_report (is_x IN varchar2)
    return // what to return?
    is
      row_i_s  inside_sales%rowtype;
      row_o_s  ouside_sales%rowtype; 
    begin
      case is_x
      when 'equipment' 
      then
         select * 
         into row_i_s 
         from inside_sales;
      else
         select * 
         into row_o_s 
         from outside_sales;
      end;
      return // what to return?
    end;
```

Comment: hey thanks alot, i will just can the report writer and write something else

Comment: I did not get you. Please exaplin.